# Function returns none, but when i print the result in the function it prints the right thing

Tags: python, function

This function below is returning `None` even though when I print the result, it print the right thing. But when I `return` it it returns `None`.

The function fills a hexagonal board with stones. The board class is a dictionary with a few functions.

When I `print(board.board)` it prints something like this:

```
{-1: {2: 3}, 0: {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 3}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2}, 2: {0: 2, 1: 2}}
```

but when it returns, it's `None`. I even tried to make a normal dictionary and return it, but it still returns none.

```
def fill_board(board, size, stone_stones, stone_index):
    if len(stone_stones) > 0:
        board_copy = base.Board(size)
        make_board_copy(board, board_copy)

        for x in range(-size, size):
            for y in range(-size, size):
                board_copy_copy = base.Board(size)
                make_board_copy(board, board_copy_copy)
                counter = 0
                for cell in stone_stones[0]:
                    p, q = cell
                    if board_copy_copy.inBoard((p+x), (q+y)) and board_copy_copy.board[p+x][q+y] == 0:
                        counter += 1
                if counter == len(stone_stones[0]):
                    for cell in stone_stones[0]:
                        p, q = cell
                        board_copy_copy.board[p+x][q+y] = stone_index[0][0]
                    if is_board_filled_(board_copy_copy):
                        print('xd_done', board_copy_copy.board)
                        print(board_copy_copy.board)
                        board_return = board_copy_copy.board.copy()
                        return board_return
                    else:
                        fill_board(board_copy_copy, size, stone_stones[1:], stone_index[1:])
    else:
        print('xd', board.board, is_board_filled_(board))
        print(board.board)
        if is_board_filled_(board):
            board_return = board.board.copy()
            return board_return
```

I have tried returning the object, making a normal dictionary copy, but I wasn't able to think of anything that would fix it.

Comment: Recursive calls won't automatically return value to the original caller, only one level up the call stack. You call `else: fill_board(...` but you completely ignore what it returns.

Comment: Also not all of your code paths return a value, and the default return value is None.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning `None` because when you recursively call `fill_board` function in your `else` block, you're not returning the value.

So, instead of just having `fill_board(board_copy_copy, size, stone_stones[1:], stone_index[1:])` in your else block, try to return what the recursive call returns. Perhaps `return fill_board(board_copy_copy, size, stone_stones[1:], stone_index[1:])`.

BTW your code would need more clarity to be better reproduced.